# ggplot not assigning a variable as an aesthetic

Tags: ggplot2

I have a data frame in long format (link below). It has 3 variables: Year, Region and Value.

I want the x-axis to plot the Year, y-axis to plot the Value, and have the Region variable used as the colour aesthetic.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTF5ExEC2qs3UoUbuMqBeH8FqT-fySEIxCbiHCU-tG5aZqxJUqnLbkppDUAUgDzjIYje9BGhxp6zQlM/pub?output=csv

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
geom_point(aes(x = Year, y = Value), colour = Region)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message.

Error in list2(na.rm = na.rm, ...) : object 'Region' not found

I'm new to RStudio and ggplot and this seems like a basic error but I can't see what I've done incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the colour argument outside the `aes()` function. `aes()` function is used to map variables in your data to visual properties (aesthetics) of the plot.`'Region'` variable needs to be placed inside the `aes()` function as below,

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Year, y = Value, colour = factor(Region)))
```

I have added `colour = factor(Region)` inside the `aes()` function. By using `factor(Region)` i ensure that each unique value in the `'Region'` column is treated as a separate category.

`ggplot2` will automatically assign different colors to different regions. If you want to define your own color palette, you can use the `scale_color_manual()` function after `geom_point()`.